# Cant Select data randomly from listview

Tags: android, listview, hashmap, put

I have 2 activities.

The first activity is an activity that parses JSON data from a server to a `ListView` and the second activity is an activity that displays the data from selected values in the `ListView`.

Here's the `onClick` method of my 1st activity :

```
/**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, userList,
            R.layout.listitemviewall,
            new String[] { "namaresto", "alamatresto"}, 
            new int[] {R.id.name, R.id.address});

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    /**
     * select resto
     */

final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              

            /** 
             * move to the next activity 
             * */

            String namanya = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String alamatnya = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.address)).getText().toString();

            //Starting a new Intent
            Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InfoTab.class);

            //Sending data to another Activity
            nextScreen.putExtra("name", namanya);
            nextScreen.putExtra("address", alamatnya);

            // starting new activity
            startActivity(nextScreen);


         }
    });
```

And here is the second activity :

```
TextView txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTEST1);
TextView txtaddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextTEST2);



    //displaying data from previous activity
    Intent i = getIntent();
    // Receiving the Data
    String name = i.getStringExtra("name");
    String address = i.getStringExtra("address");

    // Displaying Received data
    txtname.setText(name);
    txtaddress.setText(address);
```

The Result, the second Activity always displays THE FIRST RECORD! Even if i clicked the second or other record in the `ListView`.

**How can i get my code to display the correct record that is selected in the `ListView`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing these lines:

```
   String namanya = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
        String alamatnya = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.address)).getText().toString();
```

to:

```
    String namanya = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
        String alamatnya = ((TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.address)).getText().toString();
```

tell me if that works for you...

Answer (score 0):

You are not picking the correct data in the onItemClick. You can retrieve the object from the list that represents that row by doing parent.getItemAtPosition(position); inside the onItemClick. That will give you the object in the list you provided to the adapter that corresponds to that row.